# How to get the different ID's of loading docks

Tags: anylogic

I would like to create a database to load my trucks at a certain time and on a certain dock. So for example truck A should load on dock 1 at 6 am. The problem is that I don't know how to get the different IDs of my docks. I create a parameter called id but don't know which ID my different docks have which I write into my database.

Database

[image: database]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4oxT.png)

agent/population_dock

[image: agent/population_dock]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dbase table "docks" with an int-column "dock_id". Fill it with as many docks as you want to create and give them an id number.

In your existing table, link the "id" column to that new table "dock_id".

When you create "Dock" agents in your population "loadDocks", you can select "loaded from database". Create 1 agent for each record in table "docks" and map the "dock_id" column to your parameter "Dock.id".

Now each dock knows its id.

Lots of AnyLogic example models use this setup, so check these out as well (search for "database"). And read around in the help, this is documented very well :)

Comment: No worries, @JackSock. If it solved your problem, please mark it as "useful" (up arrow next to my reply) so others can find it easier in the future. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future reference.